# Подскажите где найти лицензию на использование библиотеки на python

Tags: python, opencv

Интересует библиотека yolo для распознавания образов. https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот здесь:

[Ссылка на лицензии](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet?files=1).